# Data type mismatch on query in VB OleDbCommand but not in Access

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-access, type-mismatch, oledbcommand

I'm trying to insert records in an Access .mdb database from an import table (after making some modifications and joins) with data sourced from an Excel file into another table programmatically through a VB application and I am receiving a `Data type mismatch in criteria expression.` error.

I understand why this happens and combed through each column of each source table and the destination table to try and find out which column was causing the issue, but everything seemed fine.

The real odd part is that I wrote the query, saved, and tested it in Access and it runs fine, I only get the mismatch error when I try to run it from the VB application:

```
        'COPY DATA FROM IMPORT TO CASE TABLE
        cnLoad.Open()
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
        cmd.Connection = cnLoad
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 10
        cmd.CommandText = "LoadData"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cnLoad.Close()'
```

I cannot figure out why this would be happening **ONLY** when running the query from VB. I found this, and added a "dummy" column to establish data types, but I still get the error: http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/jet-incorrect-data-type-issues

Is Access less strict with type mismatches such that I'm just not catching the problem in Access while the OleDbConnection is more strict and causing problems.  Are there any methods to finding the mismatching column in question?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try taking a copy of your database, switch the copy to [ANSI 92 compatible](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T5DMn.png) mode, verify that the saved query runs in Access, and then try running the VB code against it and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but was still receiving the error, so I went back and tried inserting each of the ~50 columns one at a time. I finally found the issue and it seems that a field was being passed Yes/No when it was set to True/False.  I'm not sure if it was just that or the ANSI 92 change as well that needed to be made, but I can now run the query from VB. Thanks for the help!